# How to append all elements in a slice to a Vec?

Tags: rust

There's [Vec::push_all](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push_all), but it's marked unstable. There's also [Vec::append](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) that's similar, but is unstable as well.

Do any alternatives exist at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Extend`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) trait, which [`Vec<T>` implements](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend) (the trait is in the prelude, so you don’t need to import it).

```
one_vec.extend(another_vec)
```